# How can I normalize this table by separating it to multiples table having primary key for each table?

Tags: python, sql, r

[image: Table]

Since the title and genre fields both have multiple values, how can I redesign into two or more tables that are in 1st normal form by identifying the primary key of each table. A little insight would be a great help. I am new in SQL.

I have tried separating movies dates by adding another column, and separate rows for each movie genre type. But I don't know how should I break it to several tables.

Comment: OK so we need to see what your Tables look like.  And you need to show an example of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

A suggested basic layout is this.  Obviously add more fields as required, but this is a normalised structure allowing 1 to many relationships between movie, title and genre

table Movie:

```
         MovieID  (pk)
```

table MovieTitle:

```
          TitleID (pk)
          MovieID (fk)
```

table MovieGenre:

```
          GenreID (pk)
          MovieID (fk)
```

Answer (score 0):

In first you have to analize what you are looking.
In ex.: one movie have many types and if you are gettin many titles for diferent languages, you can get a lot of many combinations.

You need set the entity. What is your entity? A movie?
This can made your principal table: movies.
**Movies table** had some columns
MovieID (PK) | title (first title for say something) | description 
1  | short description or basic            | long description

In the other hand you have the secondarys tables like: titles_movies, genre_movies, and genre_description
This tables have some structure like this
**title_movies**
ID (PK)| title | MovieID (FK)
1  |  etc movie | 1

**genre_description**
ID (PK)| description
1  | comedy
2  | action
3  | etc

**genre_movies**
ID (PK) | GenreID (FK)| MovieID (FK)
1  | 3 (etc)  |    1

This can be one layout